# Ordering Data using sql

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a requirement where from a View  need to get result in a specific sorting order. Here is sample table:

[image: Figure 1 and 2]

Now the data has to arrange in Descending order based on the last day BASE_PERCENTAGE. So Last day is 04-Feb-2017 and the highest to lowest order is Jessie, Ricky, Jammie and Jasmine. The final output should arrange data based on BASE_PERCENTAGE, CURR_DATE and Name. Like This-

Could someone please help to how to get the same result using sql. How sql can be written to that it gives the same result.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Attached Table_View_sql.sql is having table create, Sample Data Insert and View creation. View will give the data with BASE_Percentage.

[Table View Script](http://www.filedropper.com/tableviewsql)

Comment: I don't really understand....do you want a desc order for BASE_PERCENTAGE, CURR_DATE and NAME? If so, if you put order by CURR_DATE, NAME, BASE_PERCENTAGE desc what is your output?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Hi @Kostis, If you see the output closely you will understand. First Max base percentage has to be find out. Than for that max display all rows for all the dates. likewise it will continoue.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, I tried to copy paste the result but was unable to do and also result is very big. So i had to paste the image itself. For ease i have uploaded the full code to generate the scenario. My apologies for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to tell on every row what the most recent date base_percentage is, if you want to be able to sort by it. One way to do that is something like this. You don't need to keep the LD.LastDayBase in the select output, I added it so you can easily see what the value is while testing.

If you know what the @LastDay is, you could pass it through to the query and skip the first line.

```
DECLARE @LastDay date = (select MAX(Curr_Date) from v_DailyDetails);

SELECT VD.*, LD.LastDayBase
FROM v_DailyDetails VD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        Select Name, BASE_PERCENTAGE LastDayBase
        From v_DailyDetails VD  
        Where CURR_DATE = @LastDay
    ) LD on LD.Name = VD.Name

ORDER BY LD.LastDayBase DESC, VD.CURR_DATE DESC, LD.NAME
```

Note that the order you requested means that if ALICE and BOB both had the same LastDayBase value, then you would get the following order ALICE Feb4, Bob Feb4, Alice Feb3, Bob Feb3 etc.  If you want days for a given name to be always together, you should use

ORDER BY LD.LastDayBase DESC, LD.NAME, VD.CURR_DATE DESC

Comment: Great. you sql is giving the desired output. I have found another solution using FIRST_VALUE function.